# @Startup - Wildfly Server start method if application successful deployed

Tags: wildfly, startup

How can I start a method even the server is **fully up** and running?
Currently I´m implement a file watcher.
I want to start the File watcher at start from the server.
But due to the `while()` loop in my method the server will not start and go in the timeout. Therefore I want to start the FileWatcher as soon the server and my web app deployed successful.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class FileWatcher {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init file Watcher ");
        try {
            doStartFileWatcher();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: maybe removing @Startup does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you are running something periodically for the FileWatcher class.  How about a change:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class FileWatcher {

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*",persistent = false)
    private void runFileWatcher() {
    }
}
```

The runFileWatcher method will now run every minute at the 0 second (i.e. 10:08:00AM).  Would this work better?

Comment: No, I need this adhoc. As soon a new file is in the folder I need to inform in the app

Comment: But do you have an infinite loop polling a directory or is there some event?  You could have it run, for example, every 5 seconds.  You'd add a seconds = "*/5" for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the JDK WatchService API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html